# IO Exception Error When Trying to Read a Text File

Tags: java, android

I am trying to read a text file which contains strings (separated by commas) of airport information. However, when I try to read the file, it throws and IOException. Here is the code:

```
public ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> createAirportLibrary() {

    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> airportLibrary = new ArrayList<>();
    String[] line;
    BufferedReader reader = null;

    try {

        // import the text file
        File airportsFile = new File("C:\\Users\\cjkei\\AndroidStudioProjects\\TravelTime\\app\\libs\\airports.txt");

        // read the first line of the file
        reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(airportsFile));
        line = reader.readLine().split(",");

        // loop through each line of file and add each airport to the library
        while (line != null) {
            int i = 0;
            ArrayList<String> thisAirport = new ArrayList<>();
            while (i < line.length){
                if (line[i] instanceof String){
                    thisAirport.add(line[i]);
                }
                else {
                    airportLibrary.add(thisAirport);
                    thisAirport.clear();
                }
                i++;
            }
            line = reader.readLine().split(",");
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        Context context = this;
        String text = "error reading file";
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
        Toast.makeText(context, text, duration).show();
    }
    finally {
        try {
            if (reader != null) {
                reader.close();
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            Context context = this;
            String text = "could not close reader";
            int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
            Toast.makeText(context, text, duration).show();
        }
    }
    return airportLibrary;
}
```

I tried to debug step by step, but right after the onCreate call, it shows 
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jOsbk.png).

Comment: please print out the stacktrace so you actually get an useful error message other than 'error reading file'.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try the function [Files.lines](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/file/Files.html#lines(java.nio.file.Path)). It returns a `Stream<String>` you can then iterate over the stream.

```
Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(fileName))
stream.forEach(this::doSomethingWithLine);

private void doSomethingWithLine(String line) {
  // actually do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The picture you added does not show any exception information, but it does make clear where the error is coming from:

You are confusing two environments, and trying to open a file that does not exist.

The code in your example is for an Android app, but the file path is for a file on a Windows PC.

There is no "C drive" on Android devices, and you can not have Android code read a file from your PC, even if you run it on an emulator running on said PC.

If you look carefully at the full exception message, you will see that the problem is "File not found".

To do this, you can do something like this:

```
Toast.makeText(context, "Exception: " + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

or batter yet, since you are on Android, use the logging utility:

```
Log.e("MY_APP", "Exception: " + e.toString());
e.printStackTrace();
```

If you want the file to be part of your app and read it on the Android device, put it under `assets` folder in your project and use:

```
context.getAssets().open("MyFile.txt");
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources